# Data loading from core data to table very slowly

Tags: ios, core-data

I have table in core data with 100 rows, in tableView I load filtered 25 rows. When I open this UIViewController in app it take near 2 seconds, I think it is very slowly. I test my app on iPhone 5. May be I do something wrong?
I see that cellForRowAtIndexPath method call 4 times for all rows: 1-25, then again 1-25 etc. Is it ok?
When I load just 1 row it works fast.

```
class TipsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var tips = [Tips]()

    lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? =
    {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        {
            return managedObjectContext
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }()

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var languge:String!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        languge = defaults.objectForKey("language") as! String
        fetchLog()
    }

    func fetchLog()
    {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tips")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate=NSPredicate(format: "language=%@", languge)
        if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Tips]
        {
            tips = fetchResults
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return tips.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TipsTableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellt", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TipsTableViewCell
        cell.tipsTextView?.text = tips[indexPath.row].textShort
        cell.tipsTextView.editable=false
        cell.tipsTextView.userInteractionEnabled=false
        cell.tipsTextView.textColor = UIColor(red: 0x7E/255, green: 0x7A/255, blue: 0x7F/255, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        let cell = tableView(_tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell.getHeight()
    }

    override  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
    {
        if(segue.identifier == "showDetailx"){
            var indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            var detailViewController:TipViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TipViewController
            detailViewController.tip = tips[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailx", sender: self)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
        forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if cell.respondsToSelector("setSeparatorInset:")
        {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
        if cell.respondsToSelector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:")
        {
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        }
        if cell.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:")
        {
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath function if you don't need different height for cells. This will affect the performance. If all cell has same height, you can set cell height using tableview property.  And also check the performance with commenting the function willDisplayCell.

Answer (score 0):

You have one problem on your estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath. You call there cellForRowAtIndexPath, that's why you get another calls to this method. You can remove that code and do the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return self.heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}

func heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath( indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    var sizingCell: UITableViewCell? = nil;
    var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&token) {
        sizingCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? TipsTableViewCell
    }
    return sizingCell!.frame.size.height;
}
```

This method instantiates a sizingCell using GCD to ensure it’s created only once.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answer !I get error Variable 'sizingCell' captured by a closure before being initialized

Comment: hm, if you change 'let' to 'var'  it will resolve your problem? i've  wrote it from head, so i checked it via xcode and edit my answer

Comment: i compiled that code, it's works without error. did you still have problems with performance?

Comment: Now cellForRowAtIndexPath calls once, but heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath calls five times. It  looks steel slowly

Comment: it's normally, because heightForRow calls for each cell in your uitableview. check this tutorial for swift http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift Also, maybe it's better to hardcode height constant if you have fixed cell size

Answer (score 0):

I delete  heightForRowAtIndexPath and estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and add to viewDidLoad() this:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
```